# 2011 - GUI Extension - how to remove extension button from Popups

Tags: gui-extensions, 2011-sp1

I'm trying to enable a GUI extension button on all places except `DashboardView`, `UserView`, `UserGroupView` and `PopupsView`.

To do this, I have applied `<ext:Remove>` with list of views

```
<ext:remove>
    <ext:extension id="GreetingsBtn" name="Greetings">
        <ext:apply>
            <ext:view name="DashboardView" />
            <ext:view name="PublishQueueView" />
            <ext:view name="UserView" />
            <ext:view name="UserGroupView" />
            <ext:view name="PopupsView" />
        </ext:apply>
    </ext:extension>
</ext:remove>
```

Sample configuration file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge"
               xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration"
               xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions"
               xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">
    <resources cache="true">
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </resources>
    <definitionfiles />
    <extensions>
        <ext:editorextensions>
            <ext:editorextension target="CME">
                <ext:editurls/>
                <ext:listdefinitions/>
                <ext:taskbars  />
                <ext:commands/>
                <ext:commandextensions />
                <ext:contextmenus>
                    <ext:add>
                    </ext:add>
                </ext:contextmenus>
                <ext:lists />
                <ext:tabpages />
                <ext:toolbars  />
                <ext:ribbontoolbars>
                    <ext:add>
                        <ext:extension pageid="HomePage" groupid="ManageGroup" name="Greetings" assignid="GreetingsBtn">
                            <ext:command>ExtGreetings</ext:command>
                            <ext:title>Greetings</ext:title>
                            <ext:dependencies>
                                <cfg:dependency>Greetings.Theme</cfg:dependency>
                                <cfg:dependency>Greetings.Commands</cfg:dependency>
                            </ext:dependencies>
                            <ext:apply>
                                <ext:view name="*" />
                            </ext:apply>
                        </ext:extension>
                    </ext:add>
                    <ext:remove>
                        <ext:extension id="GreetingsBtn" name="Greetings">
                            <ext:apply>
                                <ext:view name="DashboardView" />
                                <ext:view name="PublishQueueView" />
                                <ext:view name="UserView" />
                                <ext:view name="UserGroupView" />
                                <ext:view name="PopupsView" />
                            </ext:apply>
                        </ext:extension>
                    </ext:remove>
                </ext:ribbontoolbars>
            </ext:editorextension>
        </ext:editorextensions>
        <ext:dataextenders/>
        <ext:modelextensions/>
        <ext:resourceextensions/>
    </extensions>
    <commands>
        <cfg:commandset id="Greetings.Commandset">
            <cfg:command name="ExtGreetings" implementation="Extensions.Greetings.ExtGreetings" />
            <cfg:dependencies>
                <cfg:dependency>Greetings.Scripts</cfg:dependency>
            </cfg:dependencies>
        </cfg:commandset>
    </commands>
    <contextmenus />
    <localization />
    <settings>
        <defaultpage/>
        <navigatorurl/>
        <editurls/>
        <listdefinitions />
        <itemicons />
        <theme>
            <path>/Themes/Carbon</path>
        </theme>
        <customconfiguration />
    </settings>
</Configuration>
```

Unfortunately, only for the popup views it doesn't work. List of popups I have come across so far are  `InsertComponentPresentation` and `TableEditor`.

Ideally, I want to remove extension button from all `PopupsView` through configuration file only (No JS change).

I feel that technically it is possible but I didn't find a way so far.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This is the cool one:

Try this:

```
<ext:remove>
    <ext:extension id="GreetingsBtn" name="Greetings">
        <ext:apply evaluator="UIBeardcore.Extension.RemoveButtons, UIBeardcore.Extension"/>
    </ext:extension>
</ext:remove>
```

Then implement evaluator + some custom logic inside:

```
namespace UIBeardcore.Extension
{
    public class RemoveButtons : IEvaluate
    {
        public bool isApplicable(Dictionary<string, string> context)
        {
            string viewName;
            if (context.TryGetValue("forView", out viewName))
            {
                return viewName.Contains("Popup");
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution for `PopupsView`. I need to replace `<ext:view name="PopupsView" />` with popup specific view (Example: For table editor, use `<ext:view name="TableEditorPopup" />)`

```
<ext:remove>
    <ext:extension id="GreetingsBtn" name="Greetings">
        <ext:apply>
            <ext:view name="DashboardView" />
            <ext:view name="PublishQueueView" />
            <ext:view name="UserView" />
            <ext:view name="UserGroupView" />
            <ext:view name="TableEditorPopup" />
        </ext:apply>
    </ext:extension>
</ext:remove>
```

For now it works as expected for few popups. Still I need a proper solution for this. If anyone has a proper solution, please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried doing something like this: <ext:view name="*Popup" />?

Comment: @ThomasHendrickx: Yeah thomas, I have tried that as well but no luck