# Remove a default Button or Command?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I've seen several GUI extensions that add some new functionality in the form of a button in the ribbon toolbar (e.g. Save & Comment, insert footnote, etc.). The documentation describes several ways to [add elements to the UI](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-85D82E19-40BA-4B3F-A919-507A2CD4BA85).

Is there a the mechanism to hide a default button or command from users (beyond disabling such commands)?

I see [2011 - GUI Extension - how to remove extension button from Popups](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/8031/46). **Does this apply for default functionality as well?**

*Also related, there's [configuration to remove workflow related commands](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-6572EF77-F944-4801-9894-62DCE14DFBB0). Are there other toggles to turn off sets of, or individual, buttons?*

A use case could be to replace the default linking options with custom versions (e.g. instead of using the default Component link, editors might choose more specific buttons to insert specific *types* of content).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any out-of-the-box mechanism, but you could always hide a button using your own CSS -- as well as disabling the command by overwriting it and returning `false` in the `isAvailable` and `isEnabled` methods.