# Disable publish or unpublish button in ribbon tool bar or context menu in Tridion

Tags: gui-extensions

Can anyone help me to find a solution to disable publish or unpublish button in ribbon tool bar or context menu ?

Could this be achieved using command extension from Tridion GUI extension ? If yes then what would be the process to write down the configuration file and java-script file to implement this ?

Comment: PeterK explained you can disable buttons in this answer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/15406/46. Get started with a GUI extension. The Alchemy framework seems to be popular in the community as a way to get started quickly.

Comment: Instead of implementing an extension, why not just create a security group with no permission to publish?

Comment: If they shouldn't be able to publish or unpublish, remove their rights! If you want to hide it based on other conditions, this is probably worth a read: http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2011/10/2011-sdl-tridion-gui-extensions.html

Answer (score 8):

If this makes sense per your business requirement (and do not want to restrict yourself to GUI Extension), you may follow the below approach as well:

1. Create a group in Tridion CME and add all users for whom you want to disable the Publish/Unpublish button. Also, ensure none of the user is a system administrator in Tridion CME.
2. Now open publication properties for all those publication in which you want to disable these buttons
3. Navigate to the "Security" tab
4. Select the group in left side pane that you created in step 1
5. In the right pane ensure the "Publish to Content Distributor" is UnChecked (Not Allowed)
   Refer the screen shot below:
   [image]

I hope this helps.